# Magento 2: Class BaseImage does not exist

Tags: magento2, image, media-images

Today we've updated from version 2.0.6 to 2.1.2, it was everything but flawless. But I've managed to fix all te problems except one:

**When editing a product I receive this error:**

Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\BaseImage does not exist

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Okay found the problem in the catalog_eav_attribute table, there are entries directing to specific classes.

The image class path was first named:
Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\BaseImage

But is now called:
Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Image

Comment: Solve the issue thanks